# Firefox, saved passwords, and the change password dialogue

Tags: html, firefox

If a user saves the password on the login form, ff3 is putting the saved password in the change password dialoge on the profile page, even though its **not the same input name** as the login. how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using autocomplete="off" as an attribute of the text box. I've used it in the past to stop credit card details being stored by the browser but i dont know if it works with passwords. e.g. `print("<input type="text" name="cc" autocomplete="off" />");`

Answer (score 1):

I think that FF autofills fields based on the "name" attribute of the field so that if the password box has the name="password" and the change password box has the same it will fill in the same password in both places.
Try changing the name attribute of one of the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Some sites have 3 inputs for changing a password, one for re-entering the current password and two for entering the new password. If the re-entering input was first and got auto-filled, it wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go in tools->page properties->security on the page you wish to modify.